# React modal opens second modal but second modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on A React project with GraphQl back-end. I have a modal where a user can view more details about a subject. In that modal you can click delete which opens a new modal where you need to confirm if you wan't to delete. When yes is pressed it should be deleted and the modal should close. When no is pressed the modal should just close. The deleting of the subject works. If I press yes is deletes it but the modal doesn't close and when I press no the modal also doesn't close. Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

parent modal:

```
class CalenderModal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      openDeleteAppointment: false,

    };
    this.openDeleteAppointment = this.openDeleteAppointment.bind(this);
  }


  handleRemove = () => {
    this.props.onRemove();
  }

  openDeleteAppointment() {

    this.setState({
      openDeleteAppointment: true,
    })

  }


  render() {


    return (
      <React.Fragment>



          <div className="customModal">
            <div className="modal-header">

              <h5 className="customModal__text"> Appointment summary</h5>

              <button className="btn modal__button__red" onClick={() => { this.openDeleteAppointment() }}>Delete</button>

              {this.state.openDeleteAppointment &&
                <DeleteAppointmentModal appointment={this.state.id} onHide={() => this.setState({ openDeleteClient: false, id: null })} show />}

            </div>
            <div className="modal-container">

              <div className="summary">

              <button className="btn modal__button__cancel" onClick={this.handleRemove}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );



}

export default CalenderModal;
```

child modal:

```
class DeleteAppointmentModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: this.props.appointment,
        };

    }

    render() {
        const {id} = this.state
        const DELETE_MUTATION = gql`
   mutation DeleteMutation($id:ID! ) {
   deleteAppointment(id:$id) {
     id
   }
 }
     `
     console.log("delete id",this.state.id)
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {
                    <Modal
                        {...this.props}
                        size="lg"
                        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-update-client"
                        centered
                    >
                        <Modal.Header closeButton >
                            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter" className="tittle">Delete appointment </Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <div className="delete-content">
                                Are you sure you want to delete this appointment?

                            </div>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                        <button onClick={() => this.props.onHide() } className="btn no">No</button>
                            <Mutation mutation={DELETE_MUTATION}
                                variables={{id}}>
                                {/* onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')} */}

                                {deleteMutation =>
                                    <button onClick={() => { deleteMutation(); this.props.onHide() }} className="btn yes">Yes</button>


                                }
                            </Mutation>

                        </Modal.Footer>
                    </Modal>

                }
            </React.Fragment>

        );
    }
}

export default DeleteAppointmentModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On "return" of parent component change the following row:

from:

```
<DeleteAppointmentModal appointment={this.state.id} onHide={() => this.setState({ openDeleteClient: false, id: null })} show />}
```

to:

```
<DeleteAppointmentModal appointment={this.state.id} onHide={() => { this.setState({ openDeleteAppointment: false, id: null }); handleRemove(); }} show />}
```

Hope it solved the problem.

Comment: It did! I need to be more careful when I reuse my own code! Do you maybe also know how I can close the parent modal when I delete the subject in child modal? Because now I return to parent modal that still displays the deleted subject.

Comment: I've edited the "to" row of my answer to include what might lead to  the closure of the parent modal.

Answer (score 0):

From observation:

- the show prop is always `true`. set `show={this.state. openDeleteAppointment}`
- the onHide is not setting the right state. it should set `openDeleteAppointment` instead of `openDeleteClient`